# What is the energy density of a 10 solar mass black hole as if the mass is distributed throughout the volume of the event horizon.?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass-energy, event-horizon, density

I am looking for the average mass/energy density contained in the black hole per cubic  centimeter. As if the singularity did not exist.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You could work out a mass density from the [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius). In that scenario, the mass  density of the black hole decreases with increasing mass.

Comment: FWIW, the [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator) says it's 1.84212E14 g/cm^3. But note the $M^2$ in the denominator of that formula. Big black holes have very small mean densities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is exactly the density of a black hole and how can it be calculated?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26515/)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Please examine the body of the question

Comment: @JayVerreault: I believe that answer is within a factor of c^2 of what you want. Since $E=mc^2$, the energy density is something like $e=\rho c^2$. If you're looking for something else, you should be more specific.

Comment: The body says “I am looking for the average mass/energy density”, and an answer for the duplicate question gives the mass density.

Comment: @JayVerreault: If it's not a duplicate, please edit the question to clarify in what way it's different.

Comment: My apologies. I thought I had. I changed the heading not the body.

Comment: Jay, if you want to reply to people you need to use the `@UserName` syntax, or they won't get notified. You automatically get notified about our comments on your question because you're the author. But you haven't explained why the duplicate doesn't answer your question. And my earlier comment already states the mean density of a 1 solar mass black hole to several significant digits. What more do you want?