# What is the minimum density required for an object to become a black hole?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, classical-mechanics, black-holes, solid-state-physics

What is the minimum density required for an object to become a black hole?

I ask this because whenever I research about black holes it is always said to have infinite density or infinite mass.

Possibly using the radius of the sphere as a factor.

Comment: *whenever I research about black holes it is always said to have infinite density or infinite mass* Could you point to one specific reference for context? In fact, both affirmations are wrong (although discussing the density of a black hole is sort of a delicate matter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is exactly the density of a black hole and how can it be calculated?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26515/)

Comment: In our universe with Λ≈1.1e-52/m² the minimum median density of a black hole would be ρ>1.2e-26kg/m³ (the vacuum density) since the maximal BH mass where the BH and cosmic horizons (where gₜₜ=0) pop is 4.3e+52kg with a horizon radius of about 10Glyr: http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=1053#p1053

Comment: @Yukterez Nice, but hypothetical calculations - the universe is not a black hole and has a little chance of becoming one.

Comment: Density of a black hole is not a well defined concept. For example, as observed remotely, both the volume and mass inside the horizon are zero. A more meaningful question is what density becomes a point of no return in a gravitational collapse before a star becomes a black hole: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchdahl%27s_theorem